# Why do ServletResponse object not passed through filters once the output is prepared in the servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

In Head First JSP and Servlets i was reading the Filters Chapter, in that i see that when filters are used the final output(ServletResponse) that is prepared in the servlet is not passed through the filter and directly sent to the client(End User). Why is that. In the example it says response is not passed through the filter and sent directly to the client and for that we have to use Wrappers such as HttpServletResponseWrapper.

1. When filters are enabled we can intercept the request, but why is not the response not intercepted.
2. Why is that for response we create a custom response extending the HttpServletResponseWrapper.

Can some please explain

Answer (score 1):

You make a confusion. Filters can intercept and change or replace both request and response, and can act before or after servlet processing. The problem is that if you pass the original response down the chain, on return from `chain.doFilter`, it can be already committed, said differently it may have been sent to the client and it is too late to do anything with it !

Let's look how a filter works. The relevant method is `doFilter`:

```
void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    // BEFORE calling chain.doFilter, the filter can
    // modify request, wrap request and pass it to the chain, wrap the response and
    // pass a dummy response to the chain, or directly commit the response and return
    // without even calling the chain

    chain.doFilter(req, resp); // eventually pass the original or wrapped requests 
        // and responses down the chain to the Servlet (in no other Filter decides
        // to directly commit the response)

    // AFTER calling the chain, the response should have allready been committed (sent to client ...)
    // and so can no longer be changed ... unless a wrapped "dummy" response was
    // passed to the chain - in that case it is time to process the original response
}
```